# Meaning/veracity of "each state has [..] or two outgoing ϵ transitions" in Thompson's construction

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

The [dragon book lists properties](https://dengking.github.io/compiler-principle/3-Lexical-Analysis/3.7-From-Regular-Expressions-to-Automata/) of an NFA N(r) created using Thompson's construction, in particular:

> 3. Each state of N(r) other than the accepting state has either one outgoing transition on a symbol in Σ **or two outgoing transitions, both on ϵ**.

However, the same book shows NFAs created using Thompson's construction that seem to contradict that very statement, like this one:

[image: Figure 3.44: NFA for r3]

Here, nodes 3 and 5, which are not accepting states, have only one outgoing ϵ transition each. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I think they made a small mistake here, as the rules both for converting $\epsilon$ and a union of two expressions explicitly state that they include states with *one* $\epsilon$-transition to the accepting state. They probably should have said "Each state ... has either one outgoing transition in $\Sigma\cup\{\epsilon\}$ ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Highheath in the comments, you are right.

At first I found it hard to believe that I should be the first one to have found such an error in the 36+ years since this - apparently very popular - book is out. It is in its second edition since 2008, but I would have expected this part to have been in the first edition as well.

Be that as it may, the error shows up in the [errata](http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/dragon/errata.html):

[image: Errata]